# Autonomous forwardtesting

Tags: pine-script

Is it possible to forwardtest a strategy without having to leave your computer on? Because it isn't very handy, and I'd like to test my strategies during multiple days. And I can't rely on backtesting because some of my strategies need to be recomputed on every tick, not only on bars' close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be done, because TradingView doesn't provide tick data.
If that were available, you could backtest on tick data.
And even then, you'd still have the limit of the number of bars that are available, which is 20K bars for a premium subscription.
So to calculate and test a script on every tick, your only option currently is to do that on live data.
If you don't want to leave your computer on, you could rent a [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) in the cloud to run it on, which - in the end - would cost you more than just leaving your computer on.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll change the strategy then. Instead of basing it on a 15min timeframe and relying on tick data, I think I'll stop relying on tick data and use a 1min timeframe instead. The result probably won't be exactly what I wanted, but since TradingView doesn't support "autonomous" forwardtesting nor to memorize intrabar ticks values because of the rollback process, I think that's my best option since this will also allow me to backtest my strategy.